# How to sort table in HTML by number

Tags: javascript, html, sorttable.js

## How to sort tables in HTML by number

By the way, I know there are questions like this on StackOverflow but none address my issue so please don't close my question with a response of a post with a similar title, but nothing to do with my issue

### Context

I am creating a web application for a non-profit little league team. It simply displays the player info on the live stream when you select them in the web app. My client wanted it so it displays the players in order by their batting number, so I did this with the `sorttable.js` or whatever it is called but I'm having sorting issues

### Issues

For example if this is the table

| Name | Batting Order |
| --- | --- |
| Player 1 | 1 |
| Player 2 | 10 |
| Player 3 | 2 |

10 would go before 2 because it has a 1.

### What I've tried

I've tried making `1` to `01` and `2` to `02` which did work. But I can't use this because the system to calculate whose next gets confused with `02`.

### What I want

I want to be able to sort my HTML table with javascript by number in the correct order without having `10` be before `2`

### Code

In case it's needed this is the code

```
<table class='table table-hover table-dark table-bordered sortable'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <!-- <th>Picture</th> -->
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Batting Order</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="homes">

      </tbody>
```

**sorttable.js**

```
/*
  SortTable
  version 2
  7th April 2007
  Stuart Langridge, http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

  Instructions:
  Download this file
  Add <script src="sorttable.js"></script> to your HTML
  Add class="sortable" to any table you'd like to make sortable
  Click on the headers to sort

  Thanks to many, many people for contributions and suggestions.
  Licenced as X11: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/licence.html
  This basically means: do what you want with it.
*/


var stIsIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;

sorttable = {
  init: function() {
    // quit if this function has already been called
    if (arguments.callee.done) return;
    // flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
    arguments.callee.done = true;
    // kill the timer
    if (_timer) clearInterval(_timer);

    if (!document.createElement || !document.getElementsByTagName) return;

    sorttable.DATE_RE = /^(\d\d?)[\/\.-](\d\d?)[\/\.-]((\d\d)?\d\d)$/;

    forEach(document.getElementsByTagName('table'), function(table) {
      if (table.className.search(/\bsortable\b/) != -1) {
        sorttable.makeSortable(table);
      }
    });

  },

  makeSortable: function(table) {
    if (table.getElementsByTagName('thead').length == 0) {
      // table doesn't have a tHead. Since it should have, create one and
      // put the first table row in it.
      the = document.createElement('thead');
      the.appendChild(table.rows[0]);
      table.insertBefore(the,table.firstChild);
    }
    // Safari doesn't support table.tHead, sigh
    if (table.tHead == null) table.tHead = table.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];

    if (table.tHead.rows.length != 1) return; // can't cope with two header rows

    // Sorttable v1 put rows with a class of "sortbottom" at the bottom (as
    // "total" rows, for example). This is B&R, since what you're supposed
    // to do is put them in a tfoot. So, if there are sortbottom rows,
    // for backwards compatibility, move them to tfoot (creating it if needed).
    sortbottomrows = [];
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++) {
      if (table.rows[i].className.search(/\bsortbottom\b/) != -1) {
        sortbottomrows[sortbottomrows.length] = table.rows[i];
      }
    }
    if (sortbottomrows) {
      if (table.tFoot == null) {
        // table doesn't have a tfoot. Create one.
        tfo = document.createElement('tfoot');
        table.appendChild(tfo);
      }
      for (var i=0; i<sortbottomrows.length; i++) {
        tfo.appendChild(sortbottomrows[i]);
      }
      delete sortbottomrows;
    }

    // work through each column and calculate its type
    headrow = table.tHead.rows[0].cells;
    for (var i=0; i<headrow.length; i++) {
      // manually override the type with a sorttable_type attribute
      if (!headrow[i].className.match(/\bsorttable_nosort\b/)) { // skip this col
        mtch = headrow[i].className.match(/\bsorttable_([a-z0-9]+)\b/);
        if (mtch) { override = mtch[1]; }
          if (mtch && typeof sorttable["sort_"+override] == 'function') {
            headrow[i].sorttable_sortfunction = sorttable["sort_"+override];
          } else {
            headrow[i].sorttable_sortfunction = sorttable.guessType(table,i);
          }
          // make it clickable to sort
          headrow[i].sorttable_columnindex = i;
          headrow[i].sorttable_tbody = table.tBodies[0];
          dean_addEvent(headrow[i],"click", sorttable.innerSortFunction = function(e) {

          if (this.className.search(/\bsorttable_sorted\b/) != -1) {
            // if we're already sorted by this column, just
            // reverse the table, which is quicker
            sorttable.reverse(this.sorttable_tbody);
            this.className = this.className.replace('sorttable_sorted',
                                                    'sorttable_sorted_reverse');
            this.removeChild(document.getElementById('sorttable_sortfwdind'));
            sortrevind = document.createElement('span');
            sortrevind.id = "sorttable_sortrevind";
            sortrevind.innerHTML = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">5</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25B4;';
            this.appendChild(sortrevind);
            return;
          }
          if (this.className.search(/\bsorttable_sorted_reverse\b/) != -1) {
            // if we're already sorted by this column in reverse, just
            // re-reverse the table, which is quicker
            sorttable.reverse(this.sorttable_tbody);
            this.className = this.className.replace('sorttable_sorted_reverse',
                                                    'sorttable_sorted');
            this.removeChild(document.getElementById('sorttable_sortrevind'));
            sortfwdind = document.createElement('span');
            sortfwdind.id = "sorttable_sortfwdind";
            sortfwdind.innerHTML = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">6</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25BE;';
            this.appendChild(sortfwdind);
            return;
          }

          // remove sorttable_sorted classes
          theadrow = this.parentNode;
          forEach(theadrow.childNodes, function(cell) {
            if (cell.nodeType == 1) { // an element
              cell.className = cell.className.replace('sorttable_sorted_reverse','');
              cell.className = cell.className.replace('sorttable_sorted','');
            }
          });
          sortfwdind = document.getElementById('sorttable_sortfwdind');
          if (sortfwdind) { sortfwdind.parentNode.removeChild(sortfwdind); }
          sortrevind = document.getElementById('sorttable_sortrevind');
          if (sortrevind) { sortrevind.parentNode.removeChild(sortrevind); }

          this.className += ' sorttable_sorted';
          sortfwdind = document.createElement('span');
          sortfwdind.id = "sorttable_sortfwdind";
          sortfwdind.innerHTML = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">6</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25BE;';
          this.appendChild(sortfwdind);

            // build an array to sort. This is a Schwartzian transform thing,
            // i.e., we "decorate" each row with the actual sort key,
            // sort based on the sort keys, and then put the rows back in order
            // which is a lot faster because you only do getInnerText once per row
            row_array = [];
            col = this.sorttable_columnindex;
            rows = this.sorttable_tbody.rows;
            for (var j=0; j<rows.length; j++) {
              row_array[row_array.length] = [sorttable.getInnerText(rows[j].cells[col]), rows[j]];
            }
            /* If you want a stable sort, uncomment the following line */
            //sorttable.shaker_sort(row_array, this.sorttable_sortfunction);
            /* and comment out this one */
            row_array.sort(this.sorttable_sortfunction);

            tb = this.sorttable_tbody;
            for (var j=0; j<row_array.length; j++) {
              tb.appendChild(row_array[j][1]);
            }

            delete row_array;
          });
        }
    }
  },

  guessType: function(table, column) {
    // guess the type of a column based on its first non-blank row
    sortfn = sorttable.sort_alpha;
    for (var i=0; i<table.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
      text = sorttable.getInnerText(table.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[column]);
      if (text != '') {
        if (text.match(/^-?[�$�]?[\d,.]+%?$/)) {
          return sorttable.sort_numeric;
        }
        // check for a date: dd/mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yy
        // can have / or . or - as separator
        // can be mm/dd as well
        possdate = text.match(sorttable.DATE_RE)
        if (possdate) {
          // looks like a date
          first = parseInt(possdate[1]);
          second = parseInt(possdate[2]);
          if (first > 12) {
            // definitely dd/mm
            return sorttable.sort_ddmm;
          } else if (second > 12) {
            return sorttable.sort_mmdd;
          } else {
            // looks like a date, but we can't tell which, so assume
            // that it's dd/mm (English imperialism!) and keep looking
            sortfn = sorttable.sort_ddmm;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return sortfn;
  },

  getInnerText: function(node) {
    // gets the text we want to use for sorting for a cell.
    // strips leading and trailing whitespace.
    // this is *not* a generic getInnerText function; it's special to sorttable.
    // for example, you can override the cell text with a customkey attribute.
    // it also gets .value for <input> fields.

    if (!node) return "";

    hasInputs = (typeof node.getElementsByTagName == 'function') &&
                 node.getElementsByTagName('input').length;

    if (node.getAttribute("sorttable_customkey") != null) {
      return node.getAttribute("sorttable_customkey");
    }
    else if (typeof node.textContent != 'undefined' && !hasInputs) {
      return node.textContent.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
    else if (typeof node.innerText != 'undefined' && !hasInputs) {
      return node.innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
    else if (typeof node.text != 'undefined' && !hasInputs) {
      return node.text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
    else {
      switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 3:
          if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
            return node.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
          }
        case 4:
          return node.nodeValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
          break;
        case 1:
        case 11:
          var innerText = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            innerText += sorttable.getInnerText(node.childNodes[i]);
          }
          return innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
          break;
        default:
          return '';
      }
    }
  },

  reverse: function(tbody) {
    // reverse the rows in a tbody
    newrows = [];
    for (var i=0; i<tbody.rows.length; i++) {
      newrows[newrows.length] = tbody.rows[i];
    }
    for (var i=newrows.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
       tbody.appendChild(newrows[i]);
    }
    delete newrows;
  },

  /* sort functions
     each sort function takes two parameters, a and b
     you are comparing a[0] and b[0] */
  sort_numeric: function(a,b) {
    aa = parseFloat(a[0].replace(/[^0-9.-]/g,''));
    if (isNaN(aa)) aa = 0;
    bb = parseFloat(b[0].replace(/[^0-9.-]/g,''));
    if (isNaN(bb)) bb = 0;
    return aa-bb;
  },
  sort_alpha: function(a,b) {
    if (a[0]==b[0]) return 0;
    if (a[0]<b[0]) return -1;
    return 1;
  },
  sort_ddmm: function(a,b) {
    mtch = a[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3]; m = mtch[2]; d = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt1 = y+m+d;
    mtch = b[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3]; m = mtch[2]; d = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt2 = y+m+d;
    if (dt1==dt2) return 0;
    if (dt1<dt2) return -1;
    return 1;
  },
  sort_mmdd: function(a,b) {
    mtch = a[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3]; d = mtch[2]; m = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt1 = y+m+d;
    mtch = b[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3]; d = mtch[2]; m = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt2 = y+m+d;
    if (dt1==dt2) return 0;
    if (dt1<dt2) return -1;
    return 1;
  },

  shaker_sort: function(list, comp_func) {
    // A stable sort function to allow multi-level sorting of data
    // see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort
    // thanks to Joseph Nahmias
    var b = 0;
    var t = list.length - 1;
    var swap = true;

    while(swap) {
        swap = false;
        for(var i = b; i < t; ++i) {
            if ( comp_func(list[i], list[i+1]) > 0 ) {
                var q = list[i]; list[i] = list[i+1]; list[i+1] = q;
                swap = true;
            }
        } // for
        t--;

        if (!swap) break;

        for(var i = t; i > b; --i) {
            if ( comp_func(list[i], list[i-1]) < 0 ) {
                var q = list[i]; list[i] = list[i-1]; list[i-1] = q;
                swap = true;
            }
        } // for
        b++;

    } // while(swap)
  }
}

/* ******************************************************************
   Supporting functions: bundled here to avoid depending on a library
   ****************************************************************** */

// Dean Edwards/Matthias Miller/John Resig

/* for Mozilla/Opera9 */
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", sorttable.init, false);
}

/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
    document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
    var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == "complete") {
            sorttable.init(); // call the onload handler
        }
    };
/*@end @*/

/* for Safari */
if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // sniff
    var _timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
            sorttable.init(); // call the onload handler
        }
    }, 10);
}

/* for other browsers */
window.onload = sorttable.init;

// written by Dean Edwards, 2005
// with input from Tino Zijdel, Matthias Miller, Diego Perini

// http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/

function dean_addEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        // assign each event handler a unique ID
        if (!handler.$$guid) handler.$$guid = dean_addEvent.guid++;
        // create a hash table of event types for the element
        if (!element.events) element.events = {};
        // create a hash table of event handlers for each element/event pair
        var handlers = element.events[type];
        if (!handlers) {
            handlers = element.events[type] = {};
            // store the existing event handler (if there is one)
            if (element["on" + type]) {
                handlers[0] = element["on" + type];
            }
        }
        // store the event handler in the hash table
        handlers[handler.$$guid] = handler;
        // assign a global event handler to do all the work
        element["on" + type] = handleEvent;
    }
};
// a counter used to create unique IDs
dean_addEvent.guid = 1;

function removeEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.removeEventListener) {
        element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        // delete the event handler from the hash table
        if (element.events && element.events[type]) {
            delete element.events[type][handler.$$guid];
        }
    }
};

function handleEvent(event) {
    var returnValue = true;
    // grab the event object (IE uses a global event object)
    event = event || fixEvent(((this.ownerDocument || this.document || this).parentWindow || window).event);
    // get a reference to the hash table of event handlers
    var handlers = this.events[event.type];
    // execute each event handler
    for (var i in handlers) {
        this.$$handleEvent = handlers[i];
        if (this.$$handleEvent(event) === false) {
            returnValue = false;
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
};

function fixEvent(event) {
    // add W3C standard event methods
    event.preventDefault = fixEvent.preventDefault;
    event.stopPropagation = fixEvent.stopPropagation;
    return event;
};
fixEvent.preventDefault = function() {
    this.returnValue = false;
};
fixEvent.stopPropagation = function() {
  this.cancelBubble = true;
}

// Dean's forEach: http://dean.edwards.name/base/forEach.js
/*
    forEach, version 1.0
    Copyright 2006, Dean Edwards
    License: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/

// array-like enumeration
if (!Array.forEach) { // mozilla already supports this
    Array.forEach = function(array, block, context) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            block.call(context, array[i], i, array);
        }
    };
}

// generic enumeration
Function.prototype.forEach = function(object, block, context) {
    for (var key in object) {
        if (typeof this.prototype[key] == "undefined") {
            block.call(context, object[key], key, object);
        }
    }
};

// character enumeration
String.forEach = function(string, block, context) {
    Array.forEach(string.split(""), function(chr, index) {
        block.call(context, chr, index, string);
    });
};

// globally resolve forEach enumeration
var forEach = function(object, block, context) {
    if (object) {
        var resolve = Object; // default
        if (object instanceof Function) {
            // functions have a "length" property
            resolve = Function;
        } else if (object.forEach instanceof Function) {
            // the object implements a custom forEach method so use that
            object.forEach(block, context);
            return;
        } else if (typeof object == "string") {
            // the object is a string
            resolve = String;
        } else if (typeof object.length == "number") {
            // the object is array-like
            resolve = Array;
        }
        resolve.forEach(object, block, context);
    }
};
```

Comment: The code above is not what's doing the sorting. We need to see how you are actually sorting to help you? It sounds like you are sorting strings, not numbers, but hard to say without the actual code.

Comment: @ddastrodd I fixed accordingly

Comment: The library you're using isn't what we need to see.  Please show us what javascript you've written that attempts to utilize the library.  Also it would help if there were rows in your tables html, sample data to work with.

Comment: @Lucretius I didnt write any javascript to use this lib, to make it work you just add `sortable` into the class of the table and it implements everything

Comment: Well, that would be the "plug and play" way without knowing what you are doing. The alternative would be to write two or three lines of code and achieve the same result. A combination of `document.querySelectorAll()`, `Array.prototype.sort()` and `element.append()` will be helpful here.

Comment: I'm not sure how i implement that can you show me an example? @CarstenMassmann

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Why should we have to plough through a ton of code to answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do the job (without using any libraries):

```js
const tb=document.getElementById("homes"),
  trs=[...tb.children];

document.body.onclick=ev=>{
 let col= ev.target.dataset?.col;
 if(col){
  trs.sort((a,b)=>a.children[col].textContent-b.children[col].textContent);
  trs.forEach(tr=>tb.append(tr));
 }
}
```

```html
<button data-col="1">sort by number</button>
<button data-col="2">sort by batting order</button>
<table class='table table-hover table-dark table-bordered sortable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- <th>Picture</th> -->
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Batting Order</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="homes">
    <tr>
      <td>Harry</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>go</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>stop</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tony</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>wait</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) you simply need to add the "sortable" class to the table and add some css for their default style scheme like below.  One step in troubleshooting is to remove all of the "fluff" and strip down your solution to the bare minimum.  Below, for example, I've removed all of the other classes from the table as a test... it seems to be working fine and sorting appears to be giving the expected result.

To further debug your solution, add back those classes one at a time and see if/when the table stops working.

```css
/* Sortable tables */
table.sortable thead {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<table class='sortable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- <th>Picture</th> -->
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Batting Order</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="homes">
    <tr>
      <td>Player 1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player 2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player 3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player 4</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
```

According to [the documentation](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) again, if your table is created dynamically at some point after page load you can use the `.makeSortable();` function to make it sortable like this.

```js
// populate the table with data before unitializing it.

let playerstable = document.getElementById("playerstable");
sorttable.makeSortable(playerstable);
```

```css
/* Sortable tables */
/* removed ".sortable" */
table thead {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<!-- Note: Table does not have the sortable class -->
<table id="playerstable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- <th>Picture</th> -->
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Batting Order</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="homes">
    <tr>
      <td>Player 1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player 2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player 3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player 4</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
```